# ¿Cómo cambiar ruta predeterminada de Terminal de mac?

Tags: terminal, rutas, macos

Cuando voy a **`preferencias>`** las **`shell`** se abre con> elijo la opción **`"comando ruta completa"`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí completo la ruta que quiero usar (aclaro que está suelta en Macintosh HD), pero cuando reinicio la terminal me dice:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté cambiar la ruta agregando **`sudo`** al principio, pero no funcionó

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Después de ingresar la contraseña me dice **`"proceso terminado"`**, pero no me deja seguir usando la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ir a **preferencias>perfiles** allí puedes seleccionar no solo el aspecto de la ventana de la terminal si no algunas acciones y configuraciones bastante avanzadas, cómo crear tu propio perfil en mi caso tengo uno creado que llamo proyectos y esta basado en el aspecto del homebrew

[image: En mi caso ejecuta un comando que abre mi carpeta de proyectos, nada del otro mundo, pero puede ser tan avanzado como tu gustes, cómo por ejemplo crear un comando de git, abrir una conexión ssl, ejecutar alguna función especifica etc...]

En donde dice arranque ejecuta un comando que abre mi carpeta de proyectos, nada del otro mundo, pero puede ser tan avanzado como tu gustes, cómo por ejemplo crear un comando de git, abrir una conexión ssl, ejecutar alguna función especifica etc...

Recuerdas tener marcada la casita de ejecutar en un shell por que me parece es lo que hace el inicio de sesión y si no lo marcas te seguirá marcando simplemente proceso completado

Luego de eso en **preferencias>general**

Eliges el tipo de perfil que deseas que se abra al iniciar la terminal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Bueno para comenzar te recomiendo en lugar de usar la terminal integrada que pruebes con https://iterm2.com/ es gratis y tienen alunas ventajas que iras notando conforme el uso. Una vez hayas decidido usarla puedes ir a ITerm2 -> preferencias -> Profiles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]